# Unix Script: check earliest date in a folder

Tags: unix

let's say there is a directory with the name 'IN'. It contain a no. of files. i wanted to know how i can find out no. of files in a folder and the earliest and latest dates on which fille has arrived in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do like this if you include directories.

```
find IN -printf "%p\t%T@\n" | sort -n -k 2 > all_files.tmp
head -n 1 all_files.tmp # for oldest
tail -n 1 all_files.tmp # for newest
wc -l all_files.tmp     # for number of files
```

To exclude directories,

```
find IN -type f -printf "%p\t%T@\n" | sort -n -k 2 > all_files.tmp
...
```

A concern is, what is the "time" you'r looking for? "mtime" is used in preceding examples. Google "atime ctime mtime" for their differences. In ext3/4 filesystems there probably no such a thing "birth time" of a file.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion flame.

actually the time here actually is the earliest date and time on which a file arrived.

Lets say i have a directory in which first file arrived on 26th oct 2013 at 10:30 pm and the last arrived on 28th oct 2013. so i just need to it find out this time.

Comment: and please could u tell me what find IN -printf "%p\t%T@\n" is doing.

Comment: see manpage for what find is. "%p" for filename. "%T" for last modification time. Check you file system, and see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time for the "creation time" issue.